# How to prevent lost save data when upgrade app on WP8 using cpp

Tags: windows-phone-8, upgrade, restore

cpp has no IsolatedStorageSettings or IsolatedStorageFile.
so i simply using "FILE" and "fopen" to store a game data.

but when i reinstall or upgrade the apps using "Xapdeploy" or debug with vs.
the save data will lost.
so how can i mark it is as a IsolatedStorageFile.
I mean when I upgrade the app, the file will not deleted by system.

Comment: What is the path to the file you are opening/writing? Chances are you are already writing to iso store (by another name)

Comment: I fopen Game.sav in root dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save data in the `LocalFolder` (new name for Isolated Storage) for it to be persisted.

There are Windows Runtime APIs you can use from C++/CX for this which are probably the best way to go (look for StorageFolder and StorageFile in particular), especially if you want to stay portable with Windows Store apps.

However if you want to use fopen the main issue is that this takes a `char[]`, not `wchar_t[]` file name that is used by the rest of the platform. To get around this you will need...

```
void SaveToFile()
{
    // get local folder (= isolated storage)
    auto local = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
    auto localFileNamePlatformString = local->Path + "\\game.sav";

    FILE* pFile;
    auto f = _wfopen_s(&pFile, localFileNamePlatformString->Data(), L"w");
    auto res1 = fprintf(pFile, "123456789");
    auto res2 = fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.it is very useful.
and _wfopen is also enable in wp8 so we need not to covert wchar_t× to char*.
and there is a macro MAX_PATH to instead 1024. it is a system restrict length for file path.

Comment: Ah makes sense - I'm more used to the Win32 versions. I've updated the answer to use _wfopen_s which doesn't need the file name conversion and isn't a deprecated/insecure function (which fopen and _wfopen both are).

Comment: I find that you answered my 2 questions.thanks a lot. here is my new question id 15990188. can you help me?