# How to create file using C++ on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to create a file using C++ on windows phone, but I'm not familar with Win32 API, could you give some code snippets how to use them? By the way, here also I want to know that whether the spead of creating a local file with c++ is faster than c# on windows phone platform? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main challenge in C++ is finding the root directory that you can write into.

You don't need to use the Win32 protocol from C++ (and that probably the least portable option too). You also could use standard C FILE* APIs, standard C++ stream APIs or the new WinRT async file APIs.

For example using FILE* (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988970/694641).

```
void SaveToFile()
{
    // get local folder (= isolated storage)
    auto local = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
    auto localFileNamePlatformString = local->Path + "\\game.sav";

    FILE* pFile;
    auto f = _wfopen_s(&pFile, localFileNamePlatformString->Data(), L"w");
    auto res1 = fprintf(pFile, "123456789");
    auto res2 = fclose(pFile);
}
```

I wouldn't worry about the speed of the file unless you're trying to fix a known performance problem.