# Windows Phone 8 save data

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, save

I have a mutiplatform game. To save user progress I use:

- NSUserDefaults - for iOS
- android.content.SharedPreferences - for Android
- ::RegCreateKeyEx - for Win32

what should I use for Windows Phone 8 store app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to Work with files and folders in the local folder, you can use `IsolatedStorageFile` or if you want to Work with key/value pairs in the local folder, you can use `IsolatedStorageSettings`.

For more Refrence you can go here [Data for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: thanks, but as I can see `IsolatedStorageSettings` is only available in c# and vb. what about c++?

Comment: refer this if it help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053259/how-to-create-file-using-c-on-windows-phone-8

Comment: I want to be able to store and read key/value pairs whereas this link explains how to open a file for raw data storing. Isn't it possible to access `IsolatedStorageSettings` using c++?