# _wfopen_s doesn't work properly in Windows Phone app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I need to open the file that is stored in my app's package using `_wfopen_s` function, but it returns a `FILE` object with NULL `_ptr`. It happens like this:

```
  var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("test\\test.ext");
  var nativeWorker = new NativeWorker(file.Path);
  <...>
  auto err = _wfopen_s(&this->_myFile, fileName->Data(), L"rb");
```

The `err` returned is 0, but the debugger shows there's an error happened somewhere in msvcr110d.dll, and all the fields of `this->_myFile` are NULL, except `_flag` that equals 1 and `_file` that equals 3.

To find out whether it is a problem with the file itself, I wrote a snippet similar to that was shown here: [How to prevent lost save data when upgrade app on WP8 using cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977509/how-to-prevent-lost-save-data-when-upgrade-app-on-wp8-using-cpp). It looks like this:

```
  FILE *tmp;
  auto tmpPath = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path + "\\tmp.txt";
  auto tmpErr = _wfopen_s(&tmp, tmpPath->Data(), L"w");
```

The result is almost the same, except that the `_flag` property of `tmp` now equals 2.

I'm creating a standard XAML app, and this is being done inside a Windows Phone Runtime Component. But I'm pretty sure it's not the case because I've created a 3D native app, and the same happens there. It even happens in Windows Store Runtime Component being referenced from unit tests project.

I can't refuse using `FILE` struct because it is requested by 3rd party DLL I use. Maybe there is a permission I missed, or maybe there's a method to convert WinRT's `IRandomAccessStream` to `FILE` so I could just use `StorageFile`'s API? The last would make my life so much easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was the lack of experience :) Seems like the 3rd party DLL that I compiled uses different C++ Runtime than Windows Runtime component, so the problem is incompatibility of FILE * pointer. The solution is to either not pass FILE * pointer to this DLL from WinRT component (and use other funcs), or try to build both DLL and WinRT component using the same runtime (though I'm not sure it's possible because it seems that Windows Runtime components use special "app" runtime).

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of the fopen family of functions.  The `FILE*` returned is non-null; the `_ptr` member of the pointed-to `FILE` may be null.

The `_ptr` member points to the position in the stream buffer at which the next read or write will take place.  The buffer is lazily initialized, so since you haven't yet done any I/O, no buffer has been created for the stream.  Thus, the `_ptr` is null (and `_base` is null and `_cnt` is zero).

Your call to `_wfopen_s` is succeeding.  If it were failing, the `FILE*` itself would be null and the returned status code would be nonzero.

> Is there a method to convert WinRT's `IRandomAccessStream` to `FILE`?

No.

Comment: Oh... Thanks, I didn't know that :) But still, it throws `AccessDeniedException` for the file opened this style.

Comment: Where is the AccessDeniedException coming from?

Comment: Well, I'm using libFLAC.dll, so it comes somewhere from there. Actually, I've implemented the other way to access the file, so this particular question is not actual anymore. Though the problem persists, and I'll try to find more specific info about where does it crash. Thanks!